# How to use an interface in a callback with Golang?

Tags: go, interface, faye

I am trying to use a [Faye client for Go](https://github.com/AutogrowSystems/wray) but when I try to make an interface for the client it seems to fail due to to the type in the callback:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "github.com/autogrowsystems/wray"
)

type Message interface {
    Data() map[string]interface{}
}

type Promise interface {
    Successful() bool
}

type Subscriber interface {
    Subscribe(string, bool, func(Message)) (Promise, error)
}

func subscribeMe(subber Subscriber) {
    subber.Subscribe("/my/chan", false, func(msg Message) {
        fmt.Printf("got data: %+v", msg.Data())
    })
}

func main() {
    subscribeMe(wray.NewFayeClient("http://localhost/faye"))
    fmt.Println("all good!")
}
```

At that point it fails with the following error:

```
# command-line-arguments
main/fayetest.go:27: cannot use wray.NewFayeClient("http://localhost/faye") (type *wray.FayeClient) as type Subscriber in argument to subscribeMe:
    *wray.FayeClient does not implement Subscriber (wrong type for Subscribe method)
            have Subscribe(string, bool, func(wray.Message)) (wray.SubscriptionPromise, error)
            want Subscribe(string, bool, func(Message)) (Promise, error)
```

It seems as though it should work as the client does satisfy the interface:

```
// wray.go - wray.FayeClient
func (self *FayeClient) Subscribe(channel string, force bool, callback func(Message)) (promise SubscriptionPromise, err error) {
}

// response.go - wray.Message 
func (self Message) Data() map[string]interface{} {
}

// wray.go - wray.SubscriptionPromise
func (self SubscriptionPromise) Successful() bool {
}
```

It should work right?  Or does the callback mess up the satisfaction of the interface?

**Edit:** as an aside, I am the author of that fork of the Faye Client, is there anything I can do to make it conducive to interfaces?  Apart from ditching callbacks?

Answer (score 4):

`FayeClient.Subscribe` implements:

```
Subscribe(string, bool, func(wray.Message)) (wray.SubscriptionPromise, error)
```

and your interface Subscriber requires the function:

```
Subscribe(string, bool, func(Message)) (Promise, error)
```

Notice the different parameters of the callback function (`Message` != `wray.Message`, `Promise` != `wray.SubscriptionPromise`), and that's why your code won't compile.

You don't need to declare the interfaces `Message` and `Promise` again, just use the ones from the library.

Comment: Sorry I should have mentioned that I tried that too, but it complains that `func(Message) != func(wray.Message)`... updated the question.

Answer (score 0):

Despite what you claim, `wray.FayeClient` doesn't implement your `Subscriber` interface, because it's `Subscribe` method has a different signature from the one defined in your interface.

`Subscribe(string, bool, func(wray.Message)) (wray.SubscriptionPromise, error)` simply is not the same thing as `Subscribe(string, bool, func(Message)) (Promise, error)`. `wray.Message` may implement `Message`, but it's still a *different type*. Same goes for `wray.SubscriptionPromise` and `Promise`.

If you want to make your library more conducive to interfaces, you need to change the library itself to accept interface arguments and return interfaces instead of concrete types.

Comment: So if I make the argument in the callback an interface it should work?  Aren't I just going to have the same problem in that it would be asking for the `wray.MessageInterface` (for example) to be in the signature?